# Can I run PowerShell on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have been assigned a project to be done in Windows PowerShell. I am familiar with shell scripting but it's a new technology. I was told that its similar to shell except few syntax changes.

I have one week time to learn and understand the basics.

I tried looking for an emulator but couldn't find one. I don't have a dual system on my laptop. Help me out here.

Do I need to install Windows on my laptop so that I could practice those commands at home or there is a solution available in Ubuntu without making changes to my operating system.

Comment: Have a look at http://pash.sourceforge.net. To actually work on a complete implementation, I think you will have to install Windows.

Comment: If your computer came with windows and you still have the COA (the sticker with the reg code) you can just install virtualbox and windows inside of that.

Comment: You can also download a windows .iso, install in virtualbox and just skip activation for to have 30 days of use. http://www.askvg.com/direct-download-links-download-official-original-and-untouched-windows-7-iso-32-bit-and-64-bit/

Comment: i had a preinstalled Windows on my laptop..but i deleted the partion before installing Ubuntu..so thats not an alternative i guess :-(

Answer (score 7):

Posting this here is likely to get a thousand beardies running at you with "BASH IS BETTER THAN POWARSHELL!" If I could grow a beard, I would probably be one of them.

But if you have an assignment that involves Windows Powershell, there's little choice. There are some shells (and even modifiers existing shells like `zsh`)  that aim to pull in some of the PowerShell features but even if they're syntactially identical, the underlying data you're using just won't be the same.

In short: if you need to use Windows, use Windows. And you do.

That said, that doesn't mean you have to reinstall Windows properly. It could temporarily languish in a virtual machine (see VirtualBox). Easy to install, easier to remove, can't touch your existing setup. It'll be a bit slower than a native install but given you're just playing around with a command line, that doesn't seem like an issue at all.

Comment: thanks,i guess that's the only way left without altering my files.Moreover i myself will never switch to power-shell but i don't have a say here ,so need to work accordingly else i m fired,jobless again :-)

Answer (score 5):

PowerShell is available on Linux.

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

There's even a beginners guide:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/learning-powershell/powershell-beginners-guide.md

Answer (score 4):

for those who still needs it - MS made a move: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powershell-is-open-sourced-and-is-available-on-linux/

PowerShell on Linux, SSH to Windows box, the Dream...

Comment: Note that it's still in alpha. GitHub page [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/installation/linux.md)

Comment: Hahaha.. you posted that here QUICK! For all MSFT koolaid drinkers.. this is awesome news!